# Как менять шрифты в aiogram?

Tags: html, telegram, aiogram

пытаюсь разобраться с сменой шрифтов на aiogram. Перечеркивание, подчеркивание и жирное уже разобрался, не могу понять как именно поменять сами шрифты, например на Times New Roman. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: догадываюсь что в телеграмме нет поддержки других шрифтов

Comment: @TextPro_Bot - вот пример

Comment: это не другой шрифт, а просто другие символы, похожие на кирилицу